# Nissan vanette, low beams not working, high beams are! New relay wires still no change? It's a 1998

Tags: nissan

Work up to one head light no working on low beam. Both are working when on high beam. Checked all fuses, and the seem to be ok. Relay terminals are brand new. But after a week there is only one head light working on low beam, but both work on high beam. Any ideas out there???

Comment: I don't know about your vehicle, but often the high and low beams are two separate bulbs. Maybe the low beam bulb on that side is simply burned out and needs to be replaced?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the bulbs? If you swap them and the problem stays in the same place its a wiring issue. If the problem is now on the other side you have a faulty bulb.